# App cannot be access on kubernetes on port 3000

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have deployed a docker application onto my docker hub https://hub.docker.com/r/leexha/nodejsapp/.

I verfiied this by doing a docker pull and did a `docker run docker run -p 8000:3000 index.docker.io/leexha/nodejsapp:latest`

I am trying to deploy this into kubernetes. This is my `deploy.yml` file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: secondapp
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webapp
        image: index.docker.io/leexha/nodejsapp
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        resources:
          requests: 
            memory: 500Mi
            cpu: 0.5
          limits:
            memory: 500Mi
            cpu: 0.5
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

I then exposed the deployment as a service:

```
C:\Users\adrlee\Desktop\oracle\Web_projects>kubectl get nodes
NAME              STATUS     ROLES     AGE       VERSION
xxxxxxxxxxx   Ready      node      1d        v1.8.11
yyyyyyyyyyy    NotReady   node      1d        v1.8.11
zzzzzzzzzzz    Ready      node      1d        v1.8.11

C:\Users\adrlee\Desktop\oracle\Web_projects>kubectl get deployments
NAME       DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
firstapp   3         3         3            3           6m

C:\Users\adrlee\Desktop\oracle\Web_projects>kubectl expose deployment/firstapp --type="NodePort" --port 3000
service "firstapp" exposed

C:\Users\adrlee\Desktop\oracle\Web_projects>kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
firstapp     NodePort    10.96.156.3   <none>        3000:31872/TCP   10s
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1     <none>        443/TCP          1d
```

It seems everything is in order however when I try to access my application on the cluster (:3000) it can't be access.

So I tried to do a bit of debugging.

I did:

```
export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}                                       {{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}')
```

and I did a curl

```
curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/$POD_NAME/proxy/
```

I notice this response:

```
}
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0cu                                       rl: (6) Could not resolve host: firstapp-f85d8f76c-bqsst
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0cu                                       rl: (6) Could not resolve host: firstapp-f85d8f76c-txlng
```

Little lost what to do now. Would appreciate any help?

Comment: I believe NodePort only goes from TCP 30000 to 32XXX-something. Not sure how it behaves for 3000, probably exactly like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the type field to NodePort, the Kubernetes master will allocate a port from a range specified by `--service-node-port-range` flag (default: 30000-32767) in [kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/)

Try with a port in this default range or check the kube-apiserver service on your master for the specific custom range.